# Not going to next page even after first success attempt of login with facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am making login page where i need to login with facebook ,i succeed in that too that after first installation it ask for user password to continue with facebook, and even afetr successful attempt it will go to next activity.But after i close the app it again goes to login activity and the facebook button turns to logout.
i am not getting correct way of doing as why its not showing me next page after second time i opened the app.
here is my Login Activity:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String eml;
    private String pswrd;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status = "";
   // private Button fbbutton;
    Profile profile;
    Button login;



    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;


    SharedPreferences prefs;
    // private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    TextView tac1;
    EditText email, pass;
    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud....com/broccoli/login.php";
    public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;



    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
           // Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
           // nextActivity(profile);



        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {      }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        //AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Get_hash_key();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
               // nextActivity(newProfile);
            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();


      /* SharedPreferences sf_shared_pref = getSharedPreferences("variable", 0);
      String  on_time_login = sf_shared_pref.getString("boolean flag", "");

        if (on_time_login!=null && on_time_login.isEmpty()) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
           startActivity(intent);

        }*/

Button guest=(Button)findViewById(R.id.gbtn) ;
        guest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gst=new Intent(Login.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(gst);
            }
        });




        // AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

       // fbbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbtn);

        /*fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call private method
                onFblogin();
            }
        });*/
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                //nextActivity(profile);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent main = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                // main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
                // main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
                // main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
                main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(main);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            }
        };
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);


        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        tac1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cAcc);

        tac1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {


                                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, RegistrationForm.class));


                                    }
                                }

        );

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lbtn);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                eml = email.getText().toString();
                pswrd = pass.getText().toString();


                // new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                if (eml.trim().length() > 0 && pswrd.trim().length() > 0)

                                {
                                    if (response.trim().equals("success"))

                                    {

                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        // SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("variable", MODE_PRIVATE); // 0 - for private mode
                                        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                        // editor.putString("flag", eml);
                                        // editor.apply();

                                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));
                                        //your intent code here

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username/password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }


                                }
                            }

                        },

                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("email", eml);
                        params.put("password", pswrd);

                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }

        });
    }


    public void Get_hash_key() {
        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.zeba.broccoli", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }
    }




    /**private void onFblogin() {
        callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        try {
                            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                                        // profile2 is the new profile
                                        profile = profile_new;
                                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                                    }
                                };
                                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
                            } else {
                                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                            }

                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                            Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                                            // Application code
                                            try {
                                                String fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                                String fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                                String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                                String fb_gender = object.getString("gender");
                                                String fb_email = object.getString("email");
                                                String fb_birthday = object.getString("birthday");


                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + fb_name + " Email: " +fb_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                Intent _int = new Intent(Login.this,Home.class);
                                                startActivity(_int);


                                            }



                                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                            //use shared preferences here
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);


                            request.executeAsync();


                            //go to Home page

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                        }
                    }*/


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Facebook login
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        //nextActivity(profile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Facebook login
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        //Facebook login
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);



    }
   /* private void nextActivity(Profile profile){
        if(profile != null){
            Intent main = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
           // main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
           // main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
           // main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
            main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(main);
        }
    }*/


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
Log.d(FACEBOOK_TAG, "Access token = " + accessToken.getToken());
ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
        this.stopTracking();
        Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);
        Profile profile = currentProfile == null ? oldProfile : currentProfile;
        //doRequiredUsingFacebookUserInfo(profile);
    }
};
profileTracker.startTracking();
}
```

Use above code to get the access token after successful FB login.Check if the access token is null(gets the success callback).You can add the activity navigation intent once the profile is not null.

Comment: In FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback

Comment: i got red line on FACEBOOK_TAG

Comment: CANNOT RESOLVE THIS

Comment: You can delete that line of code..as its just a log.Or you can create a variablejust like this: private static final String FACEBOOK_TAG = "FACEBOOK";

Comment: now its not working ..its not going to next activity..even i put intent also

Comment: Please check if you get the success callback just by adding a log and checking if the log appears in Android Monitor.Also please post the activity navigation code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132189/discussion-between-z-al-and-gautami-bhandary).

Comment: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/com.example.zeba.broccoli/files/AppEventsLogger.persistedevents